# Solr DynamicFields map to Sitecore Languages

Tags: solr, sitecore8.1

Migrating from Lucene to Solr for various reasons. There is limited knowledge of Solr on my part at this time. Currently the details of the implementation are Sitecore 8.1 (Update 2) and Solr 4.10.0, per the compatibility table [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897%22here%22).

First, the schema.xml was updated following Solution 1 [here again](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897%22here%22). After running "Generate the Solr Schema.xml file" in Sitecore's control panel, the schema.xml file added a list of dynamicField elements corresponding to language codes. The initial assumption was that all the languages added to Sitecore would've been mapped, but this appears to not be the case. It appears to be more inline with what Solr supports in the base instance. It is known that one can add language codes to the schema.xml, though it seems to be tedious to add manually if the Sitecore instance has a large number of languages.

The primary concern is how the languages are being mapped from Sitecore to Solr. There are several examples of language codes needed for dynamicField elements that don't line up with Sitecore languages are even the query string that the log shows in the error message. A couple examples of the issue are shown:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=sitecore://master/{234456d1-1dcd-4b53-8b63-588d8b948a69}?lang=en-no&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_master_index] unknown field 'extension_t_nn'
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=sitecore://master/{ed3796b0-bb9f-44a4-801f-1c26ae7ca6c4}?lang=en-cn&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_master_index] unknown field 'height_t_zh'
```

It is unknown how en-no resolves to nn, or how en-cn resolves to zh. Understanding this would be ideal before simply adding these language codes to the schema.xml.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sitecore, but `en-no` resolves to `nn` (Norwegian Nynorsk) for some reason because `nn-no` is the nn language code. `en-no` isn't a valid iso language code. The same is true for `en-cn` - Chinese Simplified is `zh-ch`, and this is mapped to just `zh` for the language extension apparently.

Comment: It is quite possible this does not have a lot to do with Sitecore itself outside of being home to the language items. Invalid ISO codes is a valuable piece of information that did not cross my mind. If no other insight arises, this would be considered an answer by me.